# Grabbing parts of filename with python & boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, filenames

I just started with python and I am still a newbie , I want to create a function that grabs parts of filenames corresponding to a certain pattern these files are stored in s3 bucket.

So in my case, let's say I have 5  .txt files

Transfarm_DAT_005995_20190911_0300.txt
Transfarm_SupplierDivision_058346_20190911_0234.txt
Transfarm_SupplierDivision_058346_20200702_0245.txt
Transfarm_SupplierDivision_058346_20200703_0242.txt
Transfarm_SupplierDivision_058346_20200704_0241.txt

I want the script to go through these filenames, grab the string "Category i.e "Transfarm_DAT" and date "20190911"" and before the filename extension.

Can you point me in the direction to which Python modules and possibly guides that could assist me?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `split` and `join` functions if your filenames are always like this. Otherwise, regex is another avenue.

```
files_list = ['Transfarm_DAT_005995_20190911_0300.txt ', 'Transfarm_SupplierDivision_058346_20190911_0234.txt',
'Transfarm_SupplierDivision_058346_20200702_0245.txt', 'Transfarm_SupplierDivision_058346_20200703_0242.txt', 'Transfarm_SupplierDivision_058346_20200704_0241.txt']

category_list = []
date_list = []
for f in files_list:
    date = f.split('.')[0].split('_',2)[2]
    category = '_'.join([f.split('.')[0].split('_')[0], f.split('.')[0].split('_')[1]])
    # print(category, date)
    category_list.append(category)
    date_list.append(date)
print(category_list, date_list)
```

Output lists:

```
['Transfarm_DAT', 'Transfarm_SupplierDivision', 'Transfarm_SupplierDivision', 'Transfarm_SupplierDivision', 'Transfarm_SupplierDivision'] ['005995_20190911_0300', '058346_20190911_0234', '058346_20200702_0245', '058346_20200703_0242', '058346_20200704_0241']
```